# Proving the matrix $A$ is diagonizable without finding its eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I need to show that $A$ is a diagonizable matrix:
$$A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a & b\\ a & 0 & b\\ b & a & 0\end{bmatrix}; \space a\neq b; \space a,b \neq 0$$

Since I can't find the eigenvectors I think the best way to approach this is to see if, with the help of the characteristic polynomial, I can prove that $A$ has three different eigenvalues.

$$|A - \lambda I_{n}| = 0 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow -\lambda (\lambda^{2} - ab) -a (-a \lambda -b^{2}) + b(a^{2} + b\lambda) = 0 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow -\lambda^{3} + (ab + a^{2} + b^{2})\lambda + ab^{2} + a^{2}b = 0$$

But I didn't come to any conclusion... Maybe I'm missing on how to factorize this polynomial, or maybe there is a better approach to the problem... Can some one guide me?

Comment: It is possible to factor(ize) this polynomial. Note that the constant term is $ab(a+b)$ and the roots sum to zero, and check the most obvious possibility...

Comment: $-a, -b, a + b$ are eigenvalues. That being said, your statement is wrong for $a = 1, b = -2$ -- the resultant matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks guys... I will try to do what @Micah said

Comment: Perhaps the $2,3$ entry should be an $a$ instead of a $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong with $a = 1, b = -2$, whose [Jordan form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+normal+form+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22JordanDecompositionCalculator%22%2C+%22theMatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C1%2C-2%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C0%7D%7D%22) is
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0  & -1 & 0 \\
0  & 0  & -2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
hence it's not diagonalizable.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe the book is wrong...

Comment: @mozzarino It's not uncommon that a book has wrong times.